# Property binding error after updating to Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13, angular-language-service

I'm getting this error

> Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations"

Even thou it works fine when I run `ng serve`.

[image]
[image]

I started to get this compilation error when I updated angular to `v13`.

I already tried restarting *Vscode* and reinstalling *Angular Language Service* and installing a previous version of *Angular Language Service*... None of them works..

My `app.module.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you post complete error message.

Comment: @ShashikamalRC that is the only error message which I have posted

Comment: I faced the same issue but has no solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44453#issuecomment-991875095), disabling `Use legacy View Engine language service` solves the issue.

Go into extension settings of **Angular Language Service** and uncheck `Use legacy View Engine language service`.

[image]

Comment: That was not easy to google this answer and find the answer. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this error myself a while ago.

I searched the web for it and according to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1420), it is a problem with **intellisense** or **indexing** after running `ngcc` and nothing to do with your code. You can verify my statement by deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm i`. You will see that errors will go away but when you run `run serve` or `ng build` it will popup again. Anyway Your code will compile and run as it is with no problem but you will see that error until angular team fix this issue.

As a workaround you can wrap it in a `<ng-container>` and *(in some cases)* it will fix the error but I didn't do it myself. I'm waiting for a bugfix patch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**IN .ts file:**

```
export class Helloworld implements OnInit {
  valid: boolean = false;

   ngOnInit(){
     this.valid = true;
   }

}
```

**In HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="valid"> Hello World</div>
```

Here using Structural Binding in Angular will be able to recognize the your"valid"property.